# multiple javascript methods calls not invoked in expression

Tags: javascript

The JavaScript function

```
function tile(u,v, a,b,c,d) {
  var c0 = tileCorners[a].eval(u,v);
  var c1 = tileCorners[b].eval(u-1,v);
  var c2 = tileCorners[c].eval(u,v-1);
  var c3 = tileCorners[d].eval(u-1,v-1);
  return c0 + c1 + c2 + c3;
}
```

should be equivalent to

```
function tile(u,v, a,b,c,d) {
  return
    tileCorners[a].eval(u,v) +
    tileCorners[b].eval(u-1,v) +
    tileCorners[c].eval(u,v-1) +
    tileCorners[d].eval(u-1,v-1);
}
```

yet the second function always returns `undefined` (the debugger will not "step into" the calls to `eval`) whereas the first function behaves correctly.
Is there something about having multiple `eval` method calls in an expression that is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're a victim of the rules of **semicolon insertion.**

Try:

```
return tileCorners[a].eval(u,v) +
tileCorners[b].eval(u-1,v) +
tileCorners[c].eval(u,v-1) +
tileCorners[d].eval(u-1,v-1);
```

Your version is equivalent to:

```
return;

tileCorners[a].eval(u,v) +
tileCorners[b].eval(u-1,v) +
tileCorners[c].eval(u,v-1) +
tileCorners[d].eval(u-1,v-1);
```

Comment: Exactly. Thanks. Wow, that is an unfortunate pitfall.